# Are there any parts of LINQ I should avoid for SQL 2000?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0

I have a SQL 2000 backend.  SQL 2000 does not support Entity Framework v2.  I would like to use LINQ to manipulate collections in memory.

Assuming I do not use Entity Framework v2, are there any parts of LINQ in .NET 4 that do not work with SQL 2000?  Are TableAdapters [doing CRUD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) operations ok to use?

As far as I know, using Entity framework requires the explicit addition of a *.edmx file.  So adding `*.dmbl (linq to sql) or DataSet (*.xsd)` is not a problem.  Is this correct?  In other words, do any functions of LINQ generate incompatible code, e.g. entities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some limitations using `Skip` and `Take` in linq2Sql with SQL 2000.

MSDN:

> You must use identity members (IsPrimaryKey) when you use
>   Take or Skip against a SQL Server 2000 database. The
>   query must be against a single table (that is, not a join), or be a
>   Distinct, Except, Intersect, or Union operation, and must not include
>   a Concat operation. For more information, see the "SQL Server
>   2000 Support" section in Standard Query Operator Translation (LINQ to
>   SQL).
>
> This requirement does not apply to SQL Server 2005.

For some more info on unsupported features, see "SQL Server 2000 Support" section on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342.aspx